# Are infinite direct sums of injective sheaves flabby?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

More precisely, if we work over a scheme which is quasi-compact and quasi-separated, that is, this scheme can be coved by finitely many affine opens and the intersection of any two such affine opens is still quasi-compact, is the statement in the title true?

Comment: I'm guessing you're interested in the case of infinite direct sums?

Comment: For Noetherian topological spaces there is more general fact (which is Lemma III 2.8 Hartshorne) saying that direct limit of flabby sheaves is flabby.